# How can I test cases of Fermat's Last Theorem in Python

Tags: python

Exercise 5.3. Fermat’s Last Theorem says that there are no positive integers a, b, and c such that

a^n + b^n = c^n

for any values of n greater than 2.

1. Write a function named check_fermat that takes four parameters—a, b, c and n—and that checks to see if Fermat’s theorem holds. If n is greater than 2 and it turns out to be true that

a^n + b^n = c^n

the program should print, “Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!” Otherwise the program should print, “No, that doesn’t work.”

2. Write a function that prompts the user to input values for a, b, c and n, converts them to integers, and uses check_fermat to check whether they violate Fermat’s theorem.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble understanding?  The exercise is quite clear, and even tells you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: You might get a better response if your question title were along the lines of "How can I test cases of Fermat's Last Theorem in Python"

Comment: I am confused of the former one since it didn't give me the value of a,b,c, but how can i calculate parameters?

Comment: You don't calculate the parameters. They're parameters.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, show us what you have done so far to solve it and then explain what you are still having trouble with.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just write a program that prints "No, that doesn't work" no matter what the input variables are, since you know the theorem is true?  Don't you believe in mathematics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def check_fermat(a, b, c, n):
    if n > 2 and (a**n + b**n == c**n):
        print("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!")
    else:
        print("No, that doesn’t work.")

def check_numbers():
    a = int(input("Choose a number for a: "))
    b = int(input("Choose a number for b: "))
    c = int(input("Choose a number for c: "))
    n = int(input("Choose a number for n: "))
    return check_fermat(a, b, c, n)

check_numbers()
```

Probably will always return "No, that doesn't work" ....

Comment: If it doesn't, it's either a computer malfunction or the most surprising mathematical result of all time.

Comment: 0, 0, 0, 3: Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong! :-)   (If we're checking `n`, we might as well verify that the other inputs match the conditions of Fermat's theorem too..)